# Force Julius re-interpolation in Yesod or how to avoid double-tagging the server in client-heavy app

Tags: haskell, yesod

My scenario: a site displays a bunch of rows from a persistent backend. The user may add to those rows ajax-style (i.e. without leaving the current site.) When the submit button is hit, I want two things to happen without loading another page:

- the new row should be sent to the server as a JSON object and added to the DB there.
- the new row should be added *immediately* to the table and be visible.

Additionally,

- When the user refreshes the site, the table should look the same as it did after adding a bunch of rows. Error handling is tricky, but possible, and not my (current) question.

---

My implementation is along the lines of:

```
getHomeR = do
  records ← runDB $ selectList …
  defaultLayout $ do
    $(widgetFile "tableWidget")
```

The *crucial* part is, that I don't want to render these rows to HTML
*serverside*, I want that to happen *clientside*, since the client has to be
*capable* of rendering them! (and maintaining client- and server- side code
that render exactly the same thing in exactly the same way strikes me as an
error-prone approach.)

So instead, I put the `records` in a JS variable via julius interpolation:

```
var records = #{toJSON records}; // the Haskell value containing the data.

renderRow = function(jsonObject) { … }
appendRowToTable = function(row) { … }

$(document).ready(function() {
    $.each(records, function(i,v) {
        appendRowToTable(renderRow(v));
    });
});
```

This was the most elegant solution to the problem that I could come up with. It
avoids having to make a *separate* ajax call to read out the records, i.e. I know I could add a route that fetches the records freshly from the DB and add it to the JS, but that strikes me as inefficient: it involves one more round-trip that I'd like to avoid. Instead,
the JS and the HTML get built on the first request, and everything is sent over in one
happy bunch. The problem now happens on reload:

---

While the contents of the `records` Haskell variable may *change* between page
loads, the interpolation is not *re-evaluated*. Yesod assumes that the Julius
file, including all its IO-dependent interpolations, *remained the same*, but
they didn't. I end up with a `records` JavaScript variable that diverges from the
contents of the Haskell variable, which to me is unacceptable here. I need to
touch the Julius file in order to make Yesod consider updating it *(I'm using
the default scaffold. Maybe that's the problem?)*

---

TL;DR: I interpolate IO-dependent variables into Julius, but if the contents of these variables change, the client doesn't see the updated JavaScript file until I change the timestamp of the Julius file manually. I'd like the JavaScript file to be re-interpolated when the contents of the IO action change. Alternatively, we could assume that they change on every request (i.e. is there some sort of expiration period I could set to zero?)

Thanks for reading this wall o' text :-)

---

So it seems that this is actually a bug in Yesod, as Michael Snoyman has pointed out. I opened this [issue](https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod/issues/567) on github.

Comment: I encountered the same problem when I ran my app with `yesod devel`, but it didn't happen when I ran the app directly like `./mysampleapp Development`. I'd also like to hear how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a bug, I'm able to reproduce it fairly easily in a `yesod devel` site. Can you open up a ticket in the issue tracker so it doesn't get lost?

Comment: Thanks! I opened an issue.